# How do i use powershell to display shared files with their share ACL?

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner with power shell and I want to find a way in which I could display the directory of all shared folders along with their shared access control lists and "directory access control list". i tried using net share for the shared folders but i don't know how to use the directories mentioned in that for "get access control list". And with the "get access control list" how do i display the access each has e.g who has full access or just write or delete privileges etc. I am trying to replicate the results of Microsoft baseline security analyzer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always share your current code so we can help you easier.

But because you are new, I will write some for you. :)
There is a cmdlet for that purpose called `Get-SmbShareAccess`
Fore example if you run: `Get-SmbShareAccess -Name C$` you will get the return (in my case):

```
Name ScopeName AccountName              AccessControlType AccessRight
---- --------- -----------              ----------------- -----------
C$   *         BUILTIN\Administrators   Allow             Full       
C$   *         BUILTIN\Backup Operators Allow             Full       
C$   *         NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE Allow             Full
```

You can then filter the properties with `Select-Object` if you want, for example to remove the ScopeName parameter from the output.

Then if you would like to view multiple shares you can loop it with `Foreach`.

```
$shares = Get-SMBShare
Foreach($share in $shares){Get-SmbShareAccess -Name $share.Name}
```

`Get-SMBShare` lists all shares on the machine that is running the script.

If you would like to take it a bit further and view shares on multiple servers you could use `Invoke-Command` for example but that is a bigger step.

Hope that puts you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I definitely will the next time.

Comment: Please mark the answer as "Solved" with the mark to the left of my answer :)